# multiple intents for modifying an intent of a sentence?

Tags: nltk, nlp

Say I have a sentence like 'I refuse to fly' or 'I'd like to fly'. I also have a sentence like 'I don't want to sit'. When training custom intents in one of the available NLU engines (rasa/wit/luis), what's the best way to go for modeling:
Naively I could have: RefuseFlyIntent,WantFlyIntent,and RefuseSit and WantSit

More sophisticated, have set of intents FlyIntent, SitIntent, WantIntent, RefuseIntent, and have my code process the combinations.

same question can apply for other cases, like how to model the difference between You Like To Fly and I Like To Fly

I'm sure there are known methodologies for that, wanted to understand what they are. If you could give me links to literature about it, would be great.

many thanks,
Lior